# AWS EMR 5.20 and Java version support

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I would like to know if Amazon EMR 5.20 AMI support Java 9?

I could not find the information here.
I would be interested in using Spark 2.4.0 with JDK 9 and Scala 2.12.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding jdk, spark only support jdk8 officially. Since the scala team itself seems to target LTS versions (github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/559), I doubt jdk9 will ever be officially supported by spark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can not use Scala 2.12.x with Spark 2.4.0 (btw, there is experimental support, see the comments). As stated in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading), to use Spark 2.4.0, you will need to use a compatible Scala version which is 2.11.x family.

Secondly, from [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html), JDK9+ is compatible with Scala 2.11.12 but it is [incomplete](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-9--up-compatibility-notes).

Finally, AWS EMR 5.20 uses Apache Spark 2.4.0. You can check JDK version from command line in your master node.

```
>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
# "b" means "build"
# Version number is 8u191, which also means JDK 8 Update 191
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Or, you can directly run `spark-shell` command which will print both Scala (2.11.12) and JDK version (JDK8).

I hope it helps!

**NOTE:** Another [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html#w2aac14c30) also states that Java 8 is the default JVM for cluster instances for AWS EMR 5.0.0 or later.

Comment: Scala 2.12 is now supported by Spark 2.4.0 https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html

Comment: Scala 2.12 support is a very recent merge in spark. The spark download page and doc you mention are not totally up-to-date because binaries are already available for scala 2.12 on main public jars repositories (eg. mvnrepository) and official apache mirrors (e.g. http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/apache/spark/spark-2.4.0/).  That said, I guess it'll take some time for AWS EMR team to build the switches to make 2.12 available on clusters...

Comment: Found this information regarding Spark and Java 9 (they haven't tested it yet and don't support it officially) https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/fc9ba9dcc6ad47fbd05f093b94e7e13580000d5f There is no real limitation, it seems they have solved the biggest limitation which was the incompatibility with scala 2.12

Comment: I can test this tonight but when you do spark submit in emr you'll use the provided installed libraries by EMR and if that's compiled with 2.11 then you are still bound to use 2.11, not by spark itself but by the deployment, unless they have an option, but I haven't seen any option so far

Answer (score 1):

`amazon-emr` has announced the availability of a new beta version which includes the latest `apache-spark` version at this time (2.4.4) and uses scala 2.12. 
Please check the following:

> https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-emr-6-beta-2-adds-hive-3-with-llap-support-scala-212-with-spark-244/